# Opencv converts transparency to white

Tags: python, image, opencv, transparency, webp

I have some images opened from a post request in Django. When I export the image to png, the file is exported right, and the transparency is preserved. When I export to webp format, the transparent layer becomes white. I think there is a problem with the first list of the code. The last two lines work just fine when I use them in another project.

This is a the part of my code:

```
img = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(files[x].read(), np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
...
resized = cv2.resize(img, dimension, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
cv2.imwrite('img.webp',resized, [cv2.IMWRITE_WEBP_QUALITY, 70])
```

Update:
I checked the exported wepb image shape and i have 4 channels. When i open it in the browser, the background is white, but when i check it in VSCode, it is transparent. Splitting the images i got r - 255, b - 255, g - 255, alpha - 0 for the transparent pixels.
[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the shape of the image when you open it `print(img.shape)`

Comment: When i use a png image it is (1023, 1280, 4), and when i use a jpg image it is 3 instead of 4.

Comment: I was just checking, the forth channel is the alpha, jpg doesn't support alpha so that's why it would only be 3, I had a similar issue but my problem was that my png didn't have 4 channels, I ran your code on my machine and I cannot recreate the bug, can you provide more more code

Comment: Sure i can provide more code, but there is nothing related to images: only few conditional related to name. The only 3 lines of code related to image processing are the ones above.

Comment: so in your update you are saying that when you open the img.webp in your browser it doesn't have the transparent background, but when you open it with VScode it is fine - could this be that the browser is the issue? there may be partial if you are using safari according to here: https://caniuse.com/webp

Comment: The result is the same, no matter if i use Opera, Firefox or Chrome: white background. This is the only project where i encountered this problem. I thought it could be something wrong with the first line of code!

Comment: but its got the transparency when you open it with VScode? if so it would suggest nothing is wrong with the code and in fact it is opening it in a browser is the cause. One other thing to make sure would be to display just the forth channel using `cv2.imshow('',img[..., 3])` or `plt.imshow(img[..., 3])` it should show that the background is solid black but the angel wings are solid white

Comment: You are right. I used it in a HTML page and it was properly displayed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the image img to 4 channels that contains alpha channel